# dynamit input adding Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I want to create dynamic form with multiple rows of inputs so it automatically adds new row when focus is at last. I'm not sure what is the best way do accomplish this, my I created Punker with my solution, where I basically append empty item to model array when I detect focus on input element.

in html I have:

```
<input enter="main.addButton()" type="text" class="form-control">
```

my enter directive:

```
function enter() {
 return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function  (scope, element, attrs) {
        element.bind('focus', function () {
            scope.$apply(attrs.enter);
        })
    }
}
```

and in controller just apend to model:

```
vm.addButton = function () {
  vm.values.push({name: '', points: null});
};
```

How Can I append only when focus is on last element?
Is there any better way to do this?
Ideally I would like to have directive that I can drop on the group of inputs and it duplicates them.

Here is my complete example code: 
http://plnkr.co/edit/0vmgdk8LbfU0j6G6A2Xy?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$last`, like:

```
enter="$last && main.addButton()"
```

You can also use [`ngFocus`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) instead of `enter`:

> Specify custom behavior on focus event.

Just replace your `enter` attribute with `ng-focus` like:

```
ng-focus="$last && main.addButton()"
```

Comment: Thx for simple solution, I started experimenting with custom directives and forgot about ones build into angular. One more question, is there is any simple way to detect that when I'm on the empty inputs and I move to the next empty input it won't add? Because I want to be  able to go out to submit button for example when changing inputs with 'tab' key.